# How to get WebviewClient instance from WebView not on API 26 in Android?

Tags: android, webview, webviewclient

I'm working on an SDK for Android. As part of this SDK, I need to set my own `WebViewClient` to a `WebView` of an application where the `WebView`  and the SDK are integrated (meaning not part of my SDK).

For this reason, this `WebView` might have already been set with a `WebViewClient` and in this case, I need to get the instance of this `WebViewClient` from the `WebView` set my own `WebViewClient` to it and forward the callback methods of my `WebViewCleint` to the originally configured one that was set by the developer of the app.

I noticed that from **API V26** there is a [getWebViewClient](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#getWebViewClient()) method for the `WebView` class. but obviously, I'm looking for a way to do this on previous versions as well. Maybe there is some kind of way to do this using the support libs?

Does someone know how can I get the instance of the set WebViewClient in the WebView in older versions? using Reflection or any other method?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get the instance of the WebViewClient using reflection like so:

```
Object providerInstance = getProviderInstance();
Object contentsClientAdapter = getContentsClientAdapter(providerInstance);
Object webViewClient = getWebViewClientFromClientAdapter(contentsClientAdapter);
if (webViewClient instanceof WebViewClient) {
    mPreviousWebViewClient = (WebViewClient) webViewClient;
}
```

And those are the three methods to drill down the `WebView` object to get the `WebViewClient` object:

```
public Object getProviderInstance() {
    Object returnValue = null;
    try {
        Class<? extends WebView> mWebViewClass = mWebView.getClass();
        Field providerField = mWebViewClass.getDeclaredField("mProvider");
        providerField.setAccessible(true);
        Object mProvider = providerField.get(mWebView);
        returnValue = mProvider;

    } catch (NoSuchFieldException aE) {
        aE.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException aE) {
        aE.printStackTrace();
    }

    return returnValue;
}


private Object getContentsClientAdapter(Object aProviderInstance) {
    Object returnValue = null;
    try {
        Class<?> aClass = aProviderInstance.getClass();
        Field contentsClientAdapterField = aClass.getDeclaredField("mContentsClientAdapter");
        contentsClientAdapterField.setAccessible(true);
        Object mContentsClientAdapter = contentsClientAdapterField.get(aProviderInstance);
        returnValue = mContentsClientAdapter;

    } catch (NoSuchFieldException aE) {
        aE.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException aE) {
        aE.printStackTrace();
    }

    return returnValue;
}


private Object getWebViewClientFromClientAdapter(Object aContentsClientAdapter) {
    Object returnValue = null;
    try {
        Class<?> aClass = aContentsClientAdapter.getClass();
        Field WebViewClientField = aClass.getDeclaredField("mWebViewClient");
        WebViewClientField.setAccessible(true);
        Object mWebViewClient = WebViewClientField.get(aContentsClientAdapter);
        returnValue = mWebViewClient;

    } catch (NoSuchFieldException aE) {
        aE.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException aE) {
        aE.printStackTrace();
    }

    return returnValue;
}
```

But I'm really hoping to find some kind of another way to do the same. Something that will be less prone to breakage.

Comment: This approach seems to no longer work as of writing this comment, the mContentsClientAdapter of the WebViewChromium class no longer exists as a declared field, which seems weird given this source file https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/webview/+/f989a7846d5fe4116de1a0635a8aade09d2be7b2/chromium/java/com/android/webview/chromium/WebViewChromium.java?autodive=0%2F